# Facebook App Invites is deprecated

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-app-invites

As the latest release of Facebook SDK version **4.28.0 - November 7, 2017**, App Invites is deprecated. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android/

> With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Invites is
>   deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.

It makes the **AppInviteDialog** not working as expected (show white screen instead of list friends - Facebook app is not installed in the device), even I decreased Facebook SDK version to **4.27.0** or lower).
I tried to find out more information at offical docs but no luck.
Anyone have a solution for this trouble ?

Comment: you got any solution for this? I want to use fb only.

Comment: I think you have to find another platform, facebook threw it away.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should also consider using popular messaging apps and other social networks to leverage app invites i.e Whatsapp, Kik, Twitter, Kakao etc. [More details here](https://blog.getsocial.im/facebook-deprecates-app-invites-are-you-ready/)

Our data shows that less than 18% of users prefer inviting via FB AppInvites, whereas the other 82% of users prefer to invite friends via WhatsApp,
FB Messenger and other chat applications.

*(Disclaimer: I am founder of GetSocial)*

Comment: His name is Zaeem Zafar not Jose

Answer (score 3):

Seems there is no other option for non-game applications but to remove  Facebook app invites.
[Google Firebase invites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/) is good option we integrated recently and used side-by-side with Facebook Invites.

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying to add invites for the first time and struggled for a long time until I realized that I need to do the following:

1 - Use Game Requests ( i.e. apprequests)

2 - Enable "Deep Linking" in Basic Settings page on Facebook developer portal for each platform, you won't see the option unless you also enable "Single Sign On".

Now the notifications open directly into app store if app not installed or into the game directly if it is installed.

The great thing is you don't need an App Link!!

Answer (score 0):

Try GameRequestDialog to invite your friends. In that you can also set filter for NON APP USERS only.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer