# AppInviteDialog for fb users is not working in android above 6.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-6.0-marshmallow, facebook-invite-friends

I want to invite Facebook users. I used below code it is working fine for below android version 6.0. It is performing facebook login after login it is not displaying the friend's list.

Here is my code

```
        if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
            AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                    .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                    .setPreviewImageUrl("http://app.tweakvideos.com/image")
                    .build();
            AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
        }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: It displaying the list of users if Facebook is not login. if once fb is login it doesn't showing the facebook friends list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook App Invites is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196972/facebook-app-invites-is-deprecated)